# NodaTime - Calculate duration between two LocalTime variables that span midnight

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, nodatime

I have a requirement to calculate the duration between two times that may span midnight.

The use case is to allow the user to set up shift plans e.g. “09:00 to 17:00” or “22:00 to 06:00” and calculate the contracted time

For “09:00 to 17:00” I can use:

```
LocalTime inAt = new LocalTime(9, 0);
LocalTime outAt = new LocalTime(17, 0);

var period = Period.Between(inAt, outAt);
```

Which results in 8 hours, the answer I am looking for.

For “22:00 to 06:00” the period returns 16 hours (regardless of the order of the parameters).

```
LocalTime inAt = new LocalTime(22, 0);
LocalTime outAt = new LocalTime(6, 0);

var period = Period.Between(inAt, outAt);
var period2 = Period.Between(outAt, inAt);
```

I am guessing that this is related to daylight saving time, unless you know the dates you cannot be sure that the answer will always the 8 hours.  If the clocks go forward it would be 7, backwards would be 9.

How can I ensure that no matter what `LocalTime` values are used the period would disregard any daylight savings?  Should I use `LocalDateTime` with an arbitrary date such as 2021-01-01?

Also, am I correct in using `Period` or should I be using `Duration`?

**Update**

This seems to work however I am still wondering if there is an eaiser way of doing it?

```
LocalTime inAt = new LocalTime(22, 0);
LocalTime outAt = new LocalTime(6, 0);

var period = Period.Between(inAt, outAt, PeriodUnits.Ticks);
LocalTime? midnightAdjustedTime = null;

if (period.Ticks < 0)
{
  midnightAdjustedTime = LocalTime.Midnight + period;  
}

var duration = Duration.FromTicks(midnightAdjustedTime?.TickOfDay ?? period.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with daylight savings - it can't do, given that everything is in terms of `LocalTime`. It's about negative periods.

> For “22:00 to 06:00” the period returns 16 hours (regardless of the order of the parameters)

No, it doesn't. One returns 16 hours, the other returns -16 hours:

```cs
using NodaTime;

var start = new LocalTime(22, 0);
var end = new LocalTime(6, 0);

var startToEnd = Period.Between(start, end);
var endToStart = Period.Between(end, start);

Console.WriteLine(startToEnd);
Console.WriteLine(endToStart);
```

Output:

```
PT-16H
PT16H
```

It's not clear to me how you came to the conclusion that both returned the same value, but the fact that they *don't* return the same value is crucial to fixing the problem. The simple approach is just to add 1 day (24 hours) if the period is negative. The code you've got is almost right, but it can be done much simpler - and without using the `Ticks` unit at all:

```cs
// Note: Period.ToDuration() isn't "generally safe" due to variable lengths
// of months etc, but is okay here.
var duration = startToEnd.ToDuration();
if (duration < Duration.Zero)
{
    duration += Duration.FromDays(1);
}

Console.WriteLine(duration);
```

Comment: That makes sense.. I did notice the negative value, just didn't good job of explaining it. Thamks for your help.